# Mailed My Passport to the US for Renewal

Tags: usa, passports, passport-renewals

I permanently live abroad with my spouse. My passport was due to expire, so I sent it, along with the necessary renewal form, picture, etc, back to the US to be renewed. I'm planning on having my family send it back to me. Since there is no exit stamp from the country I now reside in, will this cause an issue for me? What will happen with my passport and renewal that I already sent in?

Comment: I wonder why you sent to to your family to have it renewed rather than use the services of you local embassy or consulate? You know you can get the old passport back (with a corner cut or a whole punched through to mark it as invalid), though I don’t remember whether that’s automatic or if you have to ask for it.

Comment: Firstly, it was a mistake on my part, but your response still doesn't answer my question or provide a response to what will happen now. I'm looking for some constructive, and helpful, information at this point. Are you able to answer my initial query?

Comment: @Chi Welcome to TSE. This purpose of comments is to ask for clarification, so there is no need to be curt to jcaron. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how Stack Exchange operates.

Comment: Although you don't ask about it, I would be concerned about your passport arriving in the mail at the US processing center. If it doesn't, you would want to report it stolen. The other concern: mailing it abroad to you. If it's not too late, you might want to see whether it can be sent to your nearest US consulate. Such materials go by secure courier from the US to its missions, not through postal service systems.

Answer (score 6):

When the State Department issues you the new passport, they will also return the old one (with some holes punched through it to invalidate it). In most instances, you can simply show the stamp in your old passport, along with your new passport.

IIRC, though, there are a few places that require stamps to be transferred to the new passport. So you may want to contact the immigration service of whatever country you're in, just to make sure.

EDIT: RedBaron suggests in a comment that you might be concerned that the US won't properly process your renewal because you don't have an exit stamp. If so: Don't worry. The US does not care about exit stamps, certainly not while processing a passport renewal. (In my own passport, which has since been renewed, I had about *three* missing exit stamps.)

Comment: I think OP is more concerned about the fact that when state (or whatever) department receives his renewal request with existing passport, there won't be an exit stamp on it for the country where OP currently resides in.

Comment: Thanks guys (RedBaron and Sneftel) this was helpful.

Comment: @Chi, if you think this was as good an answer as you are going to get, please accept the answer. (The tick under the op and down votes.)